# Auto generated help pages with return type HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I would appreciate some clarification about web api auto generated help pages.

As far as I could understand, if I return a Type it will auto generate the help page for that action with an example. But if I use HttpResponseMessage than it's understandable that it cannot guess what the response will be and can only make assumptions on the request parameters.

The reason I was using the HttpResponseMessage was because it was recommended to indicate the status code you wish to return when it may be different than 200.

So **what's the best practice approach** to be able to return your desired status codes, but still have the help pages working out the types you are returning?

Comment: You should define status codes for exceptions that differ from what is expected. In a Restful application, callers of your API will expect `200 OK` unless there is an error of some kind.

Comment: @CharlieBrown: Or other 2xx codes, such as 201 Created.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success

Comment: @SLaks exactly which is why I would appreciate your advice on this

Comment: @SLaks Thanks, I should have clarified that. Use the codes that exist unless there is none that match. In practice I rarely find an occasion to create a custom status code.

Comment: I clarified the question as I am aware of the several status codes and their uses and I don't mean to define my own status. My point is what is stated on the question

Comment: @Rivers: just checking, you already know the workaround(ex: `config.SetActualResponseType(typeof(string), "Values", "Post");`) for situation like yours where you return HttpResponseMessage...right?

Comment: @Rivers: Also, in the coming release we are introducing a new attribute called "System.Web.Http.Decsription.ResponseTypeAttriute" to which you can supply a "System.Type" indicating the actual type of the response. This way you can return HttpResponseMessage/IHttpActionResult from your action and still expect HelpPage to work as expected.

Comment: @KiranChalla I didn't know about it but your commend made me find the following blog post describing it. Could you post that as an answer so I can gladly accept it? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yaohuang1/archive/2012/10/13/asp-net-web-api-help-page-part-2-providing-custom-samples-on-the-help-page.aspx

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For these scenarios where you would need to return HttpResponseMessage, the workaround is to indicate the actual return type of that particular action using some of the helpers that HelpPage provides.
You can find the following code in the path `Areas\HelpPage\App_Start\HelpPageConfig.cs`

```
//// Uncomment the following to correct the sample response when the action returns an HttpResponseMessage with ObjectContent<string>.
//// The sample will be generated as if the controller named "Values" and action named "Post" were returning a string.
//config.SetActualResponseType(typeof(string), "Values", "Post");
```

**Note**:
In the coming release we are introducing a new attribute called `System.Web.Http.Description.ResponseTypeAttribute` to which you can supply a `System.Type` indicating the actual type of the response. This way you can return `HttpResponseMessage` or `IHttpActionResult` from your action and still expect HelpPage to work.

Comment: The `System.Web.Http.Description.ResponseTypeAttribute` is available in Web API 2.1, so I'd recommend using that approach.

Comment: Ok, but that still documents one kind of a response. I have a PUT action which may return 204, 202 or 400. The two latter have a response body

Answer (score 8):

I think the Attribute is a great idea and so I have implemented an attribute which may help others until you guys release it.

Decorate your actions with the attribute:

```
public class FooController : ApiController
{
    [ResponseType(typeof(Bar))]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Define the attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ResponseTypeAttribute : Attribute
{
   public ResponseTypeAttribute(Type type)
   {
       if (type == null)
       {
           throw new ArgumentNullException("type");
       }

       Type = type;
   }

   public Type Type { get; private set; }
}
```

Define the method to register the response types:

```
/// <summary>
///     Registers api controller actions which return HttpResponseMessage
///     and include the ResponseType attribute to be populated with web api
///     auto generated help.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="assembly">The assembly to search for</param>
public static void RegisterHelpResponseTypes(Assembly assembly)
{
    var apiControllerTypes = assembly
        .GetTypes().Where(typeof(ApiController).IsAssignableFrom);

    foreach (var apiControllerType in apiControllerTypes)
    {
        var validActions = apiControllerType.GetMethods()
            .Where(method =>
                Attribute.IsDefined(method, typeof(ResponseTypeAttribute))
                &&
                (method.ReturnType == typeof(HttpResponseMessage)));

        foreach (var action in validActions)
        {
            var responseType = (ResponseTypeAttribute)Attribute
                                    .GetCustomAttributes(action)
                                    .Single(x => x is ResponseTypeAttribute);

            var controllerName = apiControllerType.Name.Substring(0, 
                    apiControllerType.Name.LastIndexOf("Controller", 
                                        StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            var actionName = action.Name;

            GlobalConfiguration
                .Configuration
                .SetActualResponseType(responseType.Type, 
                                       controllerName, 
                                       actionName);
        }
    }
}
```

Include it on your application start:

```
RegisterHelpResponseTypes(typeof(FooController).Assembly);
```

Please let me know if you find any issues.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of usage? I added all of the above but do not see any documentation for my return type.

Comment: What exactly are you having when you navigate to the help pages of WebAPI and go to the controller/action where you decorated with the attribute?

Comment: After adding your attribute implementation, I see the sample response working correctly. But what I really want is to see the XML comments for the properties on the complex object (which is in the body of the HttpResponseMessage). Is there a way to do that using this attribute? I posted an explanation of what I am trying to do here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646987/webapi-help-page-documentation-for-return-or-parameter-model-class-properties

Comment: I see what you mean but Im afraid not, as it seems its not supported by web api (at least on the version I have).

Answer (score 8):

MVC 5 has a built in attribute to set the response type.

More information here:
http://thesoftwaredudeblog.wordpress.com/2014/01/05/webapi-2-helppage-using-responsetype-attribute-instead-of-setactualresponsetype/

Just use:

```
    ResponseType(typeof([Your_Class]))]
```

Comment: You need to add: `using System.Web.Http.Description;` to use this attribute.