# WebApi Help Page: don't escape HTML in XML documentation

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-helppages

I am using XML Documentation for my ASP.NET Web API Help Page [as shown here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-api-help-pages).
I would like to know if there is a way to include html in the comments such that it will be rendered on the web page, instead of it being removed/ignored/escaped.
Specifically, I am looking for a way to create a newline, but being able to create bulleted lists, etc. would be great!

Ex/ I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// CRUD operations for SalesDocument<br/>
/// This is a new line
/// </summary>
[RoutePrefix("api/SalesDocument")]
public partial class SalesDocumentController : ApiController
```

And have it show on the help page like this:

```
CRUD operations for SalesDocument 
This is a new line.
```

Instead of this: (in this case, `<br/>` gets removed somehow - if I try using `<p>` tags, they are just escaped)

```
CRUD operations for SalesDocument This is a new line.
```

*I have already tried the `<para>` tag as suggested by multiple posts for tooltips, but this does not work on my help page.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In the installed `XmlDocumentationProvider.cs` file at `Areas\HelpPage`, you can look for a method called `GetTagValue`. Here modify the return value from `node.Value.Trim()` to `node.InnerXml`.

```
private static string GetTagValue(XPathNavigator parentNode, string tagName)
{
    if (parentNode != null)
    {
        XPathNavigator node = parentNode.SelectSingleNode(tagName);
        if (node != null)
        {
            return node.InnerXml; 
        } 
    }

    return null;
}
```

Now open the installed file `Areas\HelpPage\Views\Help\DisplayTemplates\ApiGroup.cshtml` and modify the following line from:

```
<p>@controllerDocumentation</p>
```

to

```
<p>@Html.Raw(controllerDocumentation)</p>
```

Comment: Fantastic! The `@Html.Raw` was the key I was missing... 1000 thanks to you good sir, you just made my day! =)

Comment: I was wondering why it wasn't working for me, then I realized it needs to be done in multiple places (depending on where you want tags to work).  The ones I did were ApiGroup.cshtml, HelpPageApiModel.cshtml and ResourceModel.cshtml (look for .Documentation and .RequestDocumentation in each).  Thought it might help the next person that finds this :)

Comment: I had to change `return parameterNode.InnerXml;` in `GetDocumentation` to work with the parameter sections

Comment: Do you think this would be worth making pull requests for the HelpPages project on GitHub?

Comment: Instead of writing html code in the comments it is proposed to just do a find and replace for new lines: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25464271/632495

Comment: Didn't help me. Has that way become useless?

Answer (score 2):

`@controllerDocumentation` does not work for me, but changing the line to`@api.Documentation` works. i.e. `@html.raw(api.Documentation)`.