# How to make ASP.NET WEB API HELP PAGES Xml Documentation Comments to have new line

Tags: asp.net-web-api, xml-documentation, asp.net-web-api-helppages

I have a rest api developed using ASP.NET WEB API. I used help pages nuget package in order to create documentation. One problem I encountered is the following. For my model objects, I have xml documentation comments and they become descriptions on the help pages for each member of the model. I want certain part of the description to be on a new line, but everything in the comment comes as one paragraph. I tried to add `<br/>` in the comments, but didn't help. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A similar question has been asked here: [Web Api Help Page- don't escape html in xml documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22356922/700926) and the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22357540/700926) (which is given by [Kiran Challa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1184056/kiran-challa) - one of the ASP.NET Web API team members) describes a work around.

I just tried it myself, and it works fine.

However, instead of adding `<br/>` to my code comments, I changed the proposed solution from:

`return node.InnerXml;`

to:

`return node.InnerXml.Replace("\r\n", "<br/>").Replace("\n", "<br/>");`

... and as pointed out in the comments, there might be several places where you need to add `@Html.Raw()`, i.e., `ApiGroup.cshtml`, `HelpPageApiModel.cshtml`, and `ResourceModel.cshtml` and some of the partial views as well.

To figure out which views I had to change, I basically just launched the debugger in Chrome to help me inspect the html and locate the files to be changed based on that.

Comment: Not sure if this would work also, but it's a bit cleaner: `return node.InnerXml.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br>");`